# Collapsing whitespace in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, tokenize, antlr4

In my grammar, I have a whitespace token that is sent to the `HIDDEN` channel:

```
SP : [ \u00A0\u000B\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I know that I can get the text of a parsed rule, including hidden tokens, with `TokenStream#getText(Context)`.  I'd like to have all whitespace collapsed when I call that.

I also know there's a `TokenStreamRewriter` for rewriting specific tokens, but I don't see a way to rewrite all of a certain type.

Is there any way to collapse all `SP` tokens to output as a single space?

Comment: At minimum, this is *almost* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25812615/138304.

Comment: Indeed.  I asked this first, then realized there was a more general question hiding within; I felt it was different enough that it didn't feel appropriate to edit the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by changing the rule to match one or more whitespace characters (`+`) and specifying an action:

```
SP : [ \u00A0\u000B\t\r\n]+ { _text = " "; } -> channel(HIDDEN);
```