# Canonicalizing token text in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Is there a way in ANTLR to mark certain tokens as having canonical output?

For example, given the grammar (excerpt)

```
words : FOO BAR BAZ
FOO : [Ff] [Oo] [Oo]
BAR : [Bb] [Aa] [Rr]
BAZ : [Bb] [Aa] [Zz]
SP : [ ] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

`words` will match "FOO BAR BAZ", "foo bar baz", "Foo bAr baZ", etc.

When I call `TokenStream#getText(Context)`, it'll return the tokens' actual text concatenated together.

Is there a way to "canonicalize" this output such that no matter what the input, all `FOO` tokens render as "Foo", `BAR` tokens render as "Bar", and `BAZ` tokens render as "Baz" (for example)?

Given any of the inputs above, I'd like to have the output "Foo Bar Baz".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the following options would work:

1. Implement your own method to obtain the text for a parse tree or range of tokens, and place the handling for certain known token types there.
2. Create your own `Token` class that knows to return the canonical form of certain tokens, and create a `TokenFactory` implementation that creates tokens of that type. Then use the `setTokenFactory` method to cause your lexer to produce those tokens.
3. Create your own `TokenStream` implementation that overrides the default behavior.
4. Explicitly specify the text in an action that runs prior to the creation of tokens:

   ```
   FOO : [Ff] [Oo] [Oo] { _text = "Foo"; };
   ```

Other options are likely available as well.